# Cannot assign to property: 'user' is a get-only property

Tags: swiftui

I am very new to SwiftUI and coding all together and cannot figure this one out. I simply want to create a button on my home tab that changes `selectedtc` (Selected team color) to the value that is set to that team. That way I can change all text and image colors to the color that the user selects throughout all of my screens. On the button, the title is listed as team 1. The action is set to change `selectedtc` to `.blue` but it states:

> Cannot assign to property: 'user' is a get-only property

Home tab code:

```swift
struct User {
    var selectedtc: Color
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User

    init() {
        self.user = User(
            selectedtc: .red)
    }
}

struct HomeTab: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()

    private var user: User {
        return viewModel.user
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Team 1") {
                user.selectedtc = Color (.blue)
            }
            Text(verbatim: "Hello")
        }
        .foregroundColor(user.selectedtc)
    }
}

#Preview {
    HomeTab()
}
```

I am not sure what to try as a I am very new to SwiftUI.

Comment: try using `viewModel.user` directly, ie remove the `private var user: User {return viewModel.user}` and replace  `user` with `viewModel.user`. This way the View is **observing** the `viewModel`

Comment: You can of course use `@State private var user = User(selectedtc: .red)` instead of the
 `ContentViewModel`, and this will work just as well.

Comment: If you are new to SwiftUI start with `let`, `@State`, `@Binding` and computed `var`, you shouldn't need `@StateObject`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would just use `viewModel.user` directly, and not use the computed property at all.

If you do want a computed property to access a value-typed property of your model, you need to add a setter as well as a getter.

```
private var user: User {
    get { viewModel.user }
    nonmutating set { viewModel.user = newValue }
}
```

The setter should be marked `nonmutating`, because you cannot mutate `self` in `body`.